# Why Color Binding doesn't work for HorizontalGridLinesBrush in DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, material-design-in-xaml

I'm using C# WPF and `MaterialDesign` Theme, I bound the Background of the `VerticalGridLinesBrush` property of `DataGrid` to a
Background of `Button` :
[image]

NOTE ↑: This works when I use Binding just like this, Not when I want to bind opacity along with it

.

**What I need:**
the Color Binding works as well, but
I want to bind the `Opacity` property of `VerticalGridLinesBrush` to the `Opacity` property of that button
[image]

**The Problem**

so I tried this in **XAML** :

```
         <DataGrid.HorizontalGridLinesBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" Opacity="0.5"/>
        </DataGrid.HorizontalGridLinesBrush>
```

and it works well:
[image]

But when I try to use Binding it doesn't work:

```
        <DataGrid.HorizontalGridLinesBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding ElementName=GENERAL_RANG,Path=Background}" Opacity="{Binding ElementName=GENERAL_RANG,Path=Opacity}"/>
        </DataGrid.HorizontalGridLinesBrush>
```

[image]

Full XAML:

```
         <DataGrid x:Name="tASKSDataGrid" 
              EnableRowVirtualization="True"
              VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
              VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
              SelectionMode="Single"
                           
              FlowDirection="RightToLeft" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Margin="26,66,230,88" CanUserDeleteRows="False" BorderThickness="1" >
        
        <!--<DataGrid.HorizontalGridLinesBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" Opacity="0.1"/>
        </DataGrid.HorizontalGridLinesBrush>-->
        
        <!--↓-->

        <DataGrid.HorizontalGridLinesBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding ElementName=MY_BUTTON,Path=Background}" Opacity="{Binding ElementName=GENERAL_RANG,Path=Opacity}"/>
        </DataGrid.HorizontalGridLinesBrush>


        <DataGrid.Columns>
                 <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="IDNUM" Binding="{Binding IDNUM, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"  Header="Number" IsReadOnly="True"  MinWidth="50" Width="auto" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="gRColumn" Binding="{Binding GR, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Visibility="Visible" Header="Personel"  Width="auto" />

          
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    
    <Button x:Name="MY_BUTTON" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="95,56,0,0"  Width="1"/>
```

I even removed Opacity Binding but it still does not work!

What should I do?

Comment: The type of Button's `Background` is Brush and it does not match Color.

Comment: @Mojtabah: What is "GENERAL_RANG" that you are tying to bind to...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `Background` property of Control is `Brush`. There are a variety of `Brush`es and `SolidColorBrush` is one of them. If you are sure that current value of `Background` is a SolidColorBrush, you can refer its `Color` property in binding.

```xml
<SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding ElementName=MY_BUTTON,Path=Background.Color}" Opacity="{Binding ElementName=GENERAL_RANG,Path=Opacity}"/>
```

However, keep in mind that the value of `Background` does not necessarily has `Color` property and this binding won't work depending on its type.

Comment: interestingly it works good if I Bind it directly like this `HorizantalGridLinesBrush="{Binding Background, ElementName=GENERAL_RANG}" `  as I explained in the picture at the beginning of my question

Comment: I don't know what kind of Brush is actually set in that Button.